# How to split columns with string after brackets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:

```
data = { title:["[US]Tomorrow Never Dies", "[CA]Stories We Tell"]}
df["Country", "Title"] = df['a'].str.split("[ ]", n = 1, expand = True)
```

I'm trying to make it look like this

```
Country      Title  
 [US]  Tomorrow Never Dies  
 [CA]    Stories We Tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["Country"] = df["Title"].str.extract(r'\[(.*?)\]')
df["Title"] = df["Title"].str.extract(r'\[.*?\]-?(.*)$')
```